# Can operators put their satellites to sleep temporarily?

Tags: mission-design, software, safe-mode

I’ve read a bit about “safe mode” and “passivation”. While one seems to be triggered autonomously, the other is used to decommission the satellite.
How does one put the mission in a temporary safe mode? Is there a term for it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Partial answer, perhaps from information on these pages someone can address better

> Can operators put their satellites to ***sleep*** temporarily?

- [Is this the longest that a spacecraft "went to sleep" and then woke up on schedule?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15371/12102)  ([@PearsonArtPhoto's answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/15372/12102) there links to [On Pluto's doorstep, New Horizons spacecraft awakens for encounter](https://hub.jhu.edu/gazette/2015/january-february/currents-new-horizons-spacecraft/))
- [WHY did Rosetta have to go into hibernation for 2.5 years?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15374/12102)
- [How does Rosetta "wake-up?"](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3443/12102)
- [Could Rosetta have been awakened from Earth if necessary?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3446/12102)

as far as

> How does one put the mission in a temporary safe mode? Is there a term for it?

That's a horse of a different color. **Safe mode** is more like "don't do anything crazy that you'll regret in the morning" where as **sleep** assumes the spacecraft is functioning normally (no health issues) and so can be trusted to enter a minimally reactive and minimally communicative state.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of a common term, but yes, you can generally command a spacecraft into a mode where it is mostly shut down. A common scenario is to save power during a solar eclipse.

Comment: Thank you. While I believe this answer is correct too, I'm making the other one - which is more comprehensive as a the correct answer.

Comment: @AGS it's also OK to not accept any answer for a few days or even a week, to allow time for even more authoritative answers. There's probably a few folks who have actual first-hand experience in these things who may only log in once or twice a week.